# Unordered List background color disappears in media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two lists for a navbar in the footer of an HTML5 page, the first list has 12 items for navigating the site, the second contains social media links and one additional item:

```
<nav id="footer_navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 5</a></li>                    
    <li><a href="#">Thing 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thing 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>                  
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">One Last Thing</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS for these lists:

```
#footer_navbar {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
}

#footer_navbar ul li {
  display:inline;
}

#footer_navbar ul li a {
  margin:0 5px;
}

#footer_navbar ul:first-child {
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

The last part separates the two lists on two lines as opposed to placing a `<br />` tag between them. I found the information on SO [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289070/two-ul-and-br-inside-div-is-this-ok-to-use). You'll notice I removed the `>` from the code suggested as my lists are not nested. I get the desired results though, if there is a reason I should leave in the `>` please let me know.

Everything works fine, and now I want to employ media queries in my CSS so that the aforementioned menu changes similar to what is shown in [THIS ARTICLE ON RWD](http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-basic-responsive-site-css-1132756) (the differences being the background color, placement on screen and margin and padding).

So I add this media query to the CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  #footer_navbar li {
    background:#222;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
  }

  #footer_navbar a {
    display:block;
    padding:3px;
  }

}
```

And when I resize the browser window or view it on my iPhone 4S, everything works correctly EXCEPT the `background:#222;` is not displaying in the `<li>` elements. I can see it in the CSS using Firebug, but the color is not being displayed. Everything else works as planned, margin and padding are correct, the links display as `block`, all good. After hours of head scratching, I have yet to figure out what it is that I am missing or doing wrong.

Any help will be gratefully received and appreciated.

**UPDATE**

A sample of this website can be seen [HERE](http://xoverr.net/test/sample1/index.html)

Comment: are there any more rules in your CSS that specify a background for the list items?

Comment: No, they are as shown here. Which is why I'm so baffled, but I will admit, styling lists has never been my strong point. And I haven't seen any good tutorials on why it should be done a certain way, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a css style

```
.footer_navbar ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

and media query css

```
.footer_navbar li {
  background:#222;
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Change the query css to

```
.footer_navbar ul li {
  background:#222;
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
}
```

and it will work.

Your `display` property of the `li` i.e `display:block` is not applied as it is taking the property from

```
.footer_navbar ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it was something small I was missing. I made the change to the test site and it works. This CSS formatting of lists has long confused me, when to style elements together, such as `ul` `li` and `a` and when to style them separately. Oddly, after hours of searching I have yet to find a good tutorial. Your explanation here helps. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Sai, do you have any recommendations as to where I could read up on proper styling of liste elements in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I got the background to change to #222 by swapping the ID's with classes. You have ID's used throughout your markup but try switching to classes until you really need that extra level of specificity. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: More specifically: I changed your markup to reflect:

 <nav class="footer_navbar">

Then changed the selection in the media query CSS and the query worked when the window was re-sized down.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I went through the style sheet and the footer on the sample page and did as you suggested, I switched out all the `footer_navbar` IDs to Classes...but it's still not working. I must be overlooking something still?

Comment: I pulled it up in an editor and got it working by swapping out only the nav id for a class. you had <nav id="footer_navbar"> and I changed it to <nav class="footer_navbar"> Then changed the media query code to reflect that change in the CSS markup.

Comment: Your new media query after I edited looks like this:

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 h3 {
  font-size:75%;
 }
 
 .container {
  margin:10px auto;
 }
 
 .footer_navbar li {
  background:#222;
  display:block;
  margin:5px;
 }

 .footer_navbar a {
  display:block;
  padding:3px;
 }
 
}

Comment: How was that not an answer to the question? I was as specific as I could be.

Comment: @TomFoolery That is what the media query looks like in the test site. I appreciate your help...what are we missing here? See the link to the test site at the bottom of my original post so you can review the code if you weren't already. :)

Comment: I took a look at the test site in the chrome dev tools and it is saying that the background styling is being inherited from footer. It isn't showing a background on the .footer_navbar ul li a. When I add the background in manually again, it shows fine.

Comment: Tom, you helped get this problem solved, so I want to thank you for your input. :)